# Virt-Manager NAT network interfaces stop working if host connection is restarted

Tags: virtualization, virt-manager

I'm running Ubuntu (Mate) 20.04 on a workstation and I often use virt-manager to host various virtual machines for testing purposes (not for production VMs).  I have found that if networking on my workstation is disabled and re-enabled, the NAT interfaces in virt-manager stop working until the host is restarted.  I believe I understand this to be related to the virtual interfaces not re-initializing and connecting to my host's NIC.  I was wondering if there was a way to get those interfaces working again without restarting the host.

Edit:
I may have solved this, but I'm leaving this open for now to see if anyone has a better method.  To replicate the issue, use the network manager indicator to uncheck Enable Networking, and then re-enable it.  Host network is working at this point. Start virt-manager and launch a VM.  VM will not get an IP address if using DHCP and will not be able to ping a host.  My workaround is to shut down the VM and virt-manager, then run these commands:

`sudo ip link set dev virbr0 down`
`sudo ip link set dev virbr0 up`

`systemctl restart libvirtd`
`sudo virsh net-destroy default`
`sudo virsh net-start default`

At this point I can open virt-manager, launch a VM, and networking operates as expected.

Comment: I may have solved this, but I'm leaving this open for now to see if anyone has a better method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn on auto-start for default network:

```
sudo virsh net-autostart default
```